# What if "rm -rf" does not work, but "ls -a" shows no files?

Tags: linux, rm

I have a folder foo in an encfs container (source: /local/home/me/Documents mountpoint: /u/me/Documents) which I cannot delete.

```
> pwd
/u/me/Documents

> mount
[..]
encfs on /local/home/me/Documents type fuse.encfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,default_permissions,user=me)

> ls -la foo
drwxr-xr-x  2 me mygrp 4096 Nov  6 10:35 ./
drwx------ 31 me mygrp 4096 Nov  6 10:47 ../

> mv foo bar

> ls -lad bar
drwxr-xr-x 2 me mygrp 4096 Nov  6 10:35 bar/

> rm -rf bar
rm: cannot remove ‘bar’: Directory not empty

> lsof bar

> echo $?
1

> mv bar /tmp
mv: inter-device move failed: ‘bar’ to ‘/tmp/bar’; unable to remove target: Is a directory

> echo "Arghhhhghgh"
Arghhhhghgh

> uname -a
Linux mybox 3.8.0-33-generic #48-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 23 09:16:58 UTC 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

> stat bar
  File: ‘bar’
  Size: 4096        Blocks: 8          IO Block: 1048576 directory
Device: 1ch/28d Inode: 81005508    Links: 2
Access: (0755/drwxr-xr-x)  Uid: ( 4711/    me)   Gid: (  311/   mygrp)
Access: 2013-11-06 10:56:47.594878110 +0100
Modify: 2013-11-06 10:35:10.000000000 +0100
Change: 2013-11-06 10:56:47.591878043 +0100
 Birth: -
```

When ever exit codes are different from 0, I made this explicit with "echo $?".

**EDIT:** I just rebooted the box, incase I missed that after some updates have been instaleld. Results stays the same. Even remounting does not help. Is there some fsck for encfs?

**EDIT:** I found another potentially useful info: The container itself is synced via Drobox. I identified the corresponding folder (which has an encrypted file name) and found inside a `.dropbox.attr` file Which behaves the same and is actually the reason why I believe the mounted folder is not removable. I disabled the dropbox client, unmounted the container and was still not able to delete, or even rename it! Also chown did not worked. Everything except chmod gives me a permission denied. Even with root I have no success. The file was a textfile, I was able to open it:

```
{"mac": {"com.apple.FinderInfo": {"data": "AAAAAAAAAABAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA="}}}
```

And even to change the content and to save it.

Comment: The 'echo "Arghhhhghgh"' is wrong, there is one h more than necessary. Should be 'echo "Arghhhghgh"' :-) :) :)

Comment: From @Ana Maria Mendes-Perei: potential danger aside, using a preceding "sudo" to the rm command should remove the file overwriting permissions / privileges.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please, double and cross check the permission you have.

The reason why I couldn't delete this was, the folder was mounted via NFS, so my local root was not able to perform anything. The folder with that `.dropbox.attr` file had only read and executable rights, so `rm .dropbox.attr` was not working as regular user.